# Java 8 Windows permissions

Tags: java, javapolicy

I am trying to add the following permissions in my `java.policy` file:

```
permission java.net.SocketPermission "127.0.0.1:1024-", "accept,connect,listen,resolve";

permission java.net.SocketPermission "127.0.0.1:28080”, "accept,connect,listen,resolve";
```

But I got the error:

```
java.security.policy: error parsing file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_191/lib/security/java.policy:
    line 50: expected [;], found [accept]
```

Does something changed in Java 8, is the syntax different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice, you have used ” instead of ", just after 28080. Change it to " and this should hopefully work!

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't see that.